# Invoke function of neutralino.js client from remote page doesn't have any response

Tags: neutralinojs

We use neutralino.js to open a remote page by point the url from neutralino.config.json to our page and also set "enableNativeAPI": true

Our index.html of the remote page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Remote Neutralino Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="neutralino.js"></script>
        <script>
            Neutralino.init();
            Neutralino.window.setTitle('This is neutralinojs');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The neutralinojs object is available, but invoking its methods would not do anything.
Does anyone have the same issue?  Please help!!!  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because of the way neutralino works.

Neutralino starts a server which serves our HTML file, and neutralino uses the `neutralino.js` file included in our HTML file.

The `neutralino.js` provides a API to interact with the Neutralino Process which is running it but since the file you're trying to open doesn't have any neutralino process to handle it.

But there is a option you can try.

You can use `Neutralino.window.create()` function to create a new Neutralino Window and tell it to open your HTML file you want.

For example:

```js
async function makeNewWindow() {
  const fileToOpen = "/resources/myOtherFile.html"
  const windowOptions = {
      icon: '/resources/icons/myOtherIcon.png',
      enableInspector: false,
      width: 500,
      height: 300,
      maximizable: false,
      exitProcessOnClose: true,
  }
  await Neutralino.window.create(fileToOpen, windowOptions);
}

Neutralino.init();
Neutralino.events.on("ready", makeNewWindow);
```

in this code as soon as you run your program and after everything is ready, `makeNewWindow()` function will be called, this function makes 2 new variables

1st variable is `fileToOpen`, this variable stores the path to the file to open.
2nd variable is `windowOptions`, this variable stores all the options which will be set for our new window.

and then finally we call `Neutralino.window.create` function, this function takes the 1st parameter to the file/url we want to open, and second parameter is a object containing the options for our window.

Read more about [`Neutralino.window.create`](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/window#windowcreateurl-windowoptions)